# Importing file as a string causes a puzzle

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I generate simple txt file and import it as follows: `a = Import["binary.txt"]; b = Import["binary.txt", "String"]`. It appears then that lengths of imported strings a and b are quite different. But why?

Comment: that's how i generate the txt file, just in case: Export["binary.txt", ExportString[RandomReal[1000, 10], "Binary", "DataFormat" -> "Real32"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import["binary.txt"]
```

in this case is equivalent to

```
Import["binary.txt", "Text"]
```

not to

```
Import["binary.txt", "String"]
```

Documentation states that 
Import["binary.txt"]
"reads a text file, taking the character encoding to be "UTF8" by default."
Whereas for format "String" documentation states that "imports a raw sequence of bytes and returns them as a Wolfram Language character string."

Comment: Thanks! Encoding really was the point, Import["binary.txt", CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"] gives the same as "string".